# How do i turn a list of numbers into its corresponding word

Tags: excel, replace, equivalent

Let's say I had a list of numbers.

---

**Code**

25

37

46

28

37

28

---

(can't post pictures so imagine that in a table)

25 = Cow

37 = Sheep

46 = Pig

28 = Chicken

I need a code I can put in the box next to it and drag down so that the correct animal appears next to the correct number.

I can't use the =if function because there's more than 7 values it could be (around 20)

I also can't just do find replace because it's going to have my entries added to it continuously.

Please help

.

The actual list is about 1000 entries with different values but this is for explanation.

Comment: Very little, i dont know alot about excel so i dont know alot to try, the =if isnt complex enough and i dont understand =vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, $C$1:$D$7, 2, 0)
```

where `$C$1:$D$7` is address of you table with codes and animals, and `A1` contains code

Comment: This hasnt helped, mainly because i dont understand what you said sorry @simoco

Comment: Ok, here is [test workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alw59382w2lqs26/simoco.xlsx). Try it.

Comment: Thank you i figured it out using your code, i didnt understand  what you metn when first reading it
=VLOOKUP(D7,$H$7:$I$10,2,FALSE)

to clarify 
D7=the cell in the code collem. $H$7:$I$10= the table of content for what code = what animal. Still dont understand the 2. FALSE = looks for an exact match.

Comment: 2 is the column you want to return - `VLOOKUP(A1, $C$1:$D$7, 2, 0)` is asking excel to find A1 in the first column of the table C1:D7, and once found, return the data that's found in column 2 of that row.